# How to improve Gnuplot html5 image quality?

Tags: html, image, canvas, gnuplot

I use gnuplot 4.6 release and 5.0 development versions on Linux, Mac, and Windows.

I tried to make basic output to relatively recent supported HTML5 canvas terminal and receive pretty blurry image on canvas.

What I did is the following in the interactive mode:

```
set terminal canvas
set output "test-canvas.html"
test
```

Here is [the result](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7392955/test-canvas.html).

The print-screen of such a html5 canvas is [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7392955/test-canvas.png).

It's svg counterpart is [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7392955/test-svg.svg).
Both are drawn by vectors but they appear very different image qualities.

Similar situation also appears on other sites, for instance, [here](http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/~merritt/gnuplot/canvas_demos/).

Does anyone know how to improve the image quality? I don't know much about HTML5 canvas but by looking into the source code, I think the image is constructed in a vectorial way, which means the image should be very crispy up to antialias capability.

Any solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with 'blurry'. There has been a bug ([#1220 Canvas: Always clear before plotting](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1220/) ) that an image was redrawn on top of the previous one on mouse-over. That resulted in ugly images. To see the effect, go e.g. to the [4.6 demo page](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_4.6/) and repeat going with the mouse over the image and outside of it.

But that is fixed in the current development version, compare with the image on http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas_5.0/ Unfortunatelty, that effect cannot be demonstrated here in the answer.

Another point:

Although the image construction suggests, that it is a vector image, which it is not. According to the [official `canvas`-element description](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-canvas-element) it is effectively a bitmap:

> The canvas element provides scripts with a resolution-dependent bitmap canvas, which can be used for rendering graphs, game graphics, art, or other visual images on the fly.

So you can get possibly better images using a larger canvas size and larger fonts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't notice there is a repetitive overlay problem for version 4.6. It is good to know. What I referred to "blurry" is that, for instance, both the images in your links appear not as clear as the svg counterpart. I attach more comparison of my original question. Thank you!